# Sabre Rest API production credentails

Tags: .net, rest, sabre

We currently have applications making use of Sabre SOAP APIs and possess production credentials. I want to start using REST APIs going forward.

1. Do I need to raise a separate request for REST API production credentials or should I be able to use the SOAP API production credentials and get the equivalent REST API client id and client secret?
2. Is there any concept similar to TAM pools with the REST API, like in SOAP?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a new set of credentials, but just need your existing SOAP credentials to be enabled for REST.

You can request that via:
https://developer.sabre.com/contact or webservices.support@sabre.com

And, here's the mapping between the SOAP and REST values:

REST userId → SOAP ‘Username’

REST group → SOAP ‘Organization’

REST domain → SOAP ‘Domain’

REST clientSecret → SOAP ‘Password’

Also, when you register to Dev Studio (developer.sabre.com) you will get a set of test credentials for REST, that you can use in test environment, prior to requesting your existing own credentials to be enabled for REST.

Finally, there's no such thing as TAM Pool for REST APIs.

Comment: Thanks for this information. It is precisely what I was after.